# Solr setting up standalone zooKeeper

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper

Im trying to setup solr cluster on jetty but with a separate standalone(not ensemble zookeeper). I manage to start zooKeeper, but I cannot upload config to zooKeeper - I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFacto
ry
        at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<clinit>(SolrZkClient.java:
66)
        at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkCLI.main(ZkCLI.java:163)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 2 more
```

I use cloud-scripts - **zkcli.bat**. Any idea why???

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide one of the various SLF4J implementation .jar files in the classpath..

Try adding slf4j-log4j12.jar and slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar to lib directory of Jetty.